# Merging different tables from different databases and retaining the database identifier?

Tags: mysql, database

I am stuck in a tricky situation. I will give a simple example to emphasize my problem.

Suppose I have two databases; **DBa** contains tables **Ta1** and **Ta2** and **DBb** with tables **Tb1** and **Tb2**. All of these tables have the same structure.

I want to merge contents of **Ta1** with **Tb1** in a joint table named **T1**, and merge **Ta2** with **Tb2** in a joint table named **T2**. Moreover, I need a way to mark that any content (or row) of **T1** and **T2** are coming from database **DBa** or **DBb**.

One work around could be to create an extra column in the joint tables, **T1** and **T2**, with DB IDs and fill in the rows of this columns with the database name from where they are coming from (i.e. **DBa** or **DBb** as the case may be). What I can think of right now is a manual way, however I believe this is due to my limited knowledge of SQL.

I would highly appreciate your thoughts on solving this problem.

P.S. All the DBs and tables are on the same MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Having SourceDbID and OriginalID columns would seem like a reasonable solution - I definitely would not put the database name into each and every row - much better to have a SourceDb table with the database name and an ID, and reference this.

Another option, if you don't anticipate bringing in data from other sources, is to have separate NULLable columns for each Source DB, e.g. DbAID, DbBID, etc. and put the original IDs into these columns.  Whilst this is less effort to query it's not as cheap (from an I/O point-of-view) to extend should another source come along.

Comment: Yeah I meant filling in some sort of DB Ids and not DB names themselves. This idea seems interesting that I create a DBID column in the original tables itself (within each DB) , fill them with some identifiers and then merge various tables across DBs using UNION? I am trying to avoid as much as manual effort involved in filling these DBids.